# Specifying ciphers and protocol 2 in .ssh/config

Tags: ssh

I would like to be able to specify in my `.ssh/config` file that ssh uses protocol 2 (command line argument `-2`), and which ciphers to use with it.

The following does not seem to work (I get bad configuration option: `Cyphers`)

```
Host XXX
    HostName YYYY
    User ZZZZ
    Compression no
    Cyphers arcfour,blowfish-cbc
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/seas/id_rsa
```

Also, how do I know which version of ssh (or OpenSSH) I am using? `which ssh` or `man ssh` does not reveal much information.

Comment: Reread your post. You spell ciphers two different ways. Hint: the spelling you used in the config file is incorrect. The manpage you are looking for is `man ssh_config`.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm . I feel dumb. `man ssh_config` was helpful though ( I was looking at `man ssh`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `Cyphers` should be typed `Ciphers`
- To specify a protocol use the syntax: `Protocol X` where X can `1` or `2` (`2` is the default)

Try `man ssh_config`